# How to perform update on dynamodb local

Tags: javascript, database, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-dynamodb

Currently I have a local image of amazon/dynamodb-local . Whenever I try to perform an update operation on the database, it creates a duplicate row instead of updating the existing record

My table definition is:

```
{
    TableName: "commission",
    KeySchema: [
      { AttributeName: "public_key", KeyType: "HASH" }, //Partition key
    ],
    AttributeDefinitions: [{ AttributeName: "public_key", AttributeType: "S" }],
    ProvisionedThroughput: {
      ReadCapacityUnits: 5,
      WriteCapacityUnits: 5,
    },
  }
```

Update query generated using NoSQL Workbench:

```
{
        TableName: "commission",
        Key: {
            "public_key": publickey
        },
        UpdateExpression: "set commission = :commission , commisison_limit = :commissionlimit ",
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {
            ":commission": commission,
            ":commissionlimit": commissionlimit
        },
        ReturnValues: "UPDATED_NEW"

    }
```

Comment: Likely your partition key isn't the same between the two records. Can you show a sample of the record you are trying to update and the record you get?

Comment: Your update query works fine for me, so I second @cementblocks response

Comment: I am using this on nodejs, so while calling the update i call it like updateTable("tz1Kys1e2ZcTYdUhG6huoJ7abcdasdasdasd","0","5")

Comment: Just a latest development, yesterday I deleted the shared-local-instance.db and re intialized all the tables and everything was working fine. But today when i restarted everything, it is back to the same thing, Ill try to post a photo @cementblocks

Comment: What is that screenshot from? Confirm that your table only has a partition key.

Comment: @cementblocks That screenshot is from NoSQL Workbench. It is a tool from Amazon that you can use to view your database

Answer (score 1):

Just a latest development, yesterday I deleted the shared-local-instance.db and re intialized all the tables and everything was working fine. But today when i restarted everything, it is back to the same thing, The first image is when i perform the update now and the second is when i try to delete the duplicate record

[image: The table after i perform the update]

[image: If i try to delete the duplicate record, i get this error]

Comment: You should update your question instead of posting an answer I think.